# jQuery animate doing same easing effect for any value

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-easing

I want to do a simple animation with jquery, but it keeps doing the same easing effect, i cant change it.

```
item.animate({
    width: "500px"
},500,"easeInSine");
```

My code is this simple. When i trigger it it just starts out slow and fast jumps to end.
I downloaded jquery ui library again, double checked that all features are selected.

Comment: what exactly do you want the code to do?

Comment: that is the nature of easing for sine

Comment: just to extend the size of a div.

Comment: I tried 5-6 efects, for every one i get the same result. Even for linear

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#mDiv" ).click(function(){
$('#myDiv').animate(
    { opacity: 0 }, // what we are animating
    'fast', // how fast we are animating
    'swing', // the type of easing
    function() { // the callback
        alert('done');
    });
    });
```

Just gave an example ..Hope it meets your needs

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/KUwht/)

Also TRY THIS

[CLOSEST DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/KUwht/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing the jQuery UI library which contains the easing functions you're trying: http://jqueryui.com/

Comment: All of the libraries were selected when i downloaded jquery ui. Do i have to download something separately?

Comment: I.e. Try loading <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Whell the problem was that i had `transition` css property on the div i wanted to animate. after removing it animate ran smoothly.